# Angular2 filtering of array with one property and display the corresponding value

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a dropdown with list of states which I am getting through services.In JSON I get list of states with id and label. For ex. `id:NJ,label:New Jersey`. I have a different response coming from backend which gives me id of 5 states- 
ex:

```
"filters": [
              {
                "name": "listedStates",
                "includedCodes": [
                  "AZ",
                  "NJ",
                  "IN",
                  "OH",
                  "WI"
                ]
              }
```

to populate the list of entire US states in the dropdown, I am iterating like this-

```
this.addressService.getStates().subscribe(
        (data) => {

            console.log(data);

        if (data) {
            //filter with filters  array
            data.states.forEach(i => {
                console.log(data.states);
                this.newBaseStatesList.push({ 'value': i.id, 'text': i.label });
                console.log(this.newBaseStatesList);
            });

        }


    },
    (error) => {
        //console.log("An error occurred ");


    }
);
```

Right now my dropdown is getting populated with all the state items in the array whereas I would want to display only 5 states in the dropdown mentioned in the filters array. The problem here is the response I am getting from backend has only ids not the labels and the dropdown should contain the labels values. So I have to somehow map these codes with the states array in such a way that these 5 states get filtered and populated.

My object is in format-

```
{
    id:NJ,
    label:New Jersey
}
```

I would like to check with the state codes in filters array with the states array and display the respective labels. Right now, the entire states are getting populated instead of the 5 states mentioned in the filters array.

Comment: How did you unparse state of the object returned from the service.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using as below

```
this.filters.forEach((filter)=>{
    filter.includedCodes.forEach((code)=>{
            this.newBaseStatesList.push(_.takeWhile(this.data.states, { 'id': code}))'
            });
    })
```

Note:I am using **Lodash**.
I am not sure the syntax that your service returns for the `this.data.states` so work need to on it based on the sample json

Comment: this.data.states return no. of objects with id and label properties for each states.Could you update your answer with angular2 way.